# How to disabled a button[update] when there is no changes in a form

Tags: angularjs, validation

```
<form role="form" id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="firstName" type="text" />
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="lastName" type="text" /> 

<button class="btn btn-info" ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine">cancel</button
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine">update</button
</form>
```

Assume that there is a list of data in a table. 
When I click a data, a modal will pop up with data on it(in the example the firstName and lastName).

Inside the modal there’s an EDIT button that when u click it, two other buttons will appear -- `CANCEL` and `UPDATE`. I want to set the update button to disabled while there is no changes yet happening in the FORM.

By using `$pristine` I found a solution, but there’s one problem:

When I try to edit the data and decide to cancel it (by resetting the current data), the next time I click `EDIT` the `UPDATE` button is already enabled even though there are no changes to the data yet.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On cancel set the form to pristine. This will set $pristine back to true which should disable the buttons.

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine" ng-click="myForm.$setPristine()">cancel</button
```

For cancel buttons I add a function in the controller to reset all fields and then set the form back to pristine which effectively resets the form.